# Rest API: Obtaining Payment ID after redirect back to merchant site

Tags: rest, paypal

This question is specific to paying with a PayPal account.

So, here's the basic workflow:

1. I initialize a payment and redirect the user to PayPal's authentication page.
2. The user logs in and authorizes payment and is redirected back to the merchant site.
3. The payment is executed by obtaining and passing the paymentId and the payerId along.

In step one, a payment id is returned before redirecting to PayPal's site for user authorization.  In step three, I need the payment id from step one in order to successfully execute the payment.  Is there a way to obtain the payment ID without storing it in a session?  The *payer*Id is passed back as a URL parameter when redirecting back to the merchant site.  There is also a token value passed along, but I'm not sure what that is used for.  All I know is that it's not the paymentId that I'm looking for.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I answered about this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18543958/paypal-rest-api-how-to-retrieve-payment-id-after-user-has-approved-the-payment/18970771#18970771

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently it has to be either session or DB or in similar lines. We suggest you generate a unique id for the transaction and use that to map to your PaymentId that you received in the response.

Comment: That's disappointing.  I, too, had been wondering the same thing.  What I don't understand is why PayPal can't pass back the payment ID in addition to the payer ID and token.  That way we wouldn't need to store the payment ID in the user's session.  PayPal has all the info on its end to do this, so they should just do it.  The other gripe I have is that none of this was mentioned in the official PayPal documentation.

Answer (score 0):

A code might look like:

```
$approvalUrl = $payment->getApprovalLink();

if ( preg_match( '/token=(EC\-[A-Z0-9]+)/', $approvalUrl, $matches ) ) {
    $token                                = $matches[1];
    $_SESSION['PAYPAL_PAYMENT'][ $token ] = $payment->getId();
} else {
    // Error message here
    return false;
}
```