# Paypal REST API: How to retrieve payment ID after user has approved the payment.

Tags: paypal

By following the guide on https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/web/accept-paypal-payment/ , I have successfully created a payment and redirect the user to approve it.

The created payment is something look like bellow, and I save it in user's session for further reference.

```
{
  "id": "PAY-6RV70583SB702805EKEYSZ6Y",
  "create_time": "2013-03-01T22:34:35Z",
  "update_time": "2013-03-01T22:34:36Z",
  "state": "created",
  "intent": "sale",
  "payer": {
    "payment_method": "paypal"
  },
  "transactions": [
    {
      "amount": {
        "total": "7.47",
        "currency": "USD",
        "details": {
          "subtotal": "7.47"
        }
      },
      "description": "This is the payment transaction description."
    }
  ],
  "links": [
    {
      "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-6RV70583SB702805EKEYSZ6Y",
      "rel": "self",
      "method": "GET"
    },
    {
      "href": "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-60U79048BN7719609",
      "rel": "approval_url",
      "method": "REDIRECT"
    },
    {
      "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-6RV70583SB702805EKEYSZ6Y/execute",
      "rel": "execute",
      "method": "POST"
    }
  ]
}
```

After user approved the payment, Paypal will redirect the user to the `return_url`. For example, `http://<return_url>?token=EC-60U79048BN7719609&PayerID=7E7MGXCWTTKK2`.

In order to execute the payment, a POST request has to made to `https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/{payment_id}/execute/`.

**Question**

The only two pieces of information provided from Paypal in the URL is `token` and `PayerID`. How can I find the corresponding `payment_id`?

**Possible Solution**

The `token` is part of the `approval_url`, parse the URL and store the `token -> payment` relationship can solve the problem. But I'm looking for a better solution that doesn't require parsing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the paypal documentation isn't clear about this. But you can do something simple to resolve your problem passing de PaymentID through a parameter in your return url.

Like this:
return_url = 'http://www.yourdomain.com/paypal/success/?**paymentID=PAY-1234567**'

When the Paypal redirect to your site, then, it will return the paymentID together with the other parameters.

Comment: I think this is the best approach, not using the paymentID but a random token to connect paypal async call. This way you can detach the session user without problem. With python pyramid I'm creating the payment sending the success url as http://localhost:6543/payment_ok/t-b37b41f1-5146-463a-b248-bad523a2fa79.

Comment: Yes Antonio, you're right! The truth is you don't have the paymentID before you sending the request. Then, sending a random token you can identify the session of the user.

Comment: This won't work.  The reason is that the payment ID is not known UNTIL AFTER the return URL has already been sent to PayPal.  The currently recommended best practice is to store the payment ID in the user's session (just make sure the session doesn't expire before either the user returns or PayPal's payment record is expunged).  It would have been best if PayPal had included the payment ID in addition to the payer ID and transaction token.  I'm not sure why they decided to omit it.  What's equally frustrating is that they didn't mention it in their documentation.

Comment: Yes you don't have the paymentID before you sending the request

Answer (score 5):

You would have to remember the Payment ID on your side (typically attached with your user session - shopping cart or order or as a session cookie) before redirecting the user to PayPal approval url. Once the is redirected back to your return Url along with the PayerID - you would need to extract the PaymentID from your user session and execute the Payment.

Comment: haven't found a better solution than parsing and making something like an arraystore linking EC-TOKEN with PAY-TOKEN

Answer (score 1):

The Payment Id can be obtained in PHP by using the following method after the first API request has returned a successful response:

```
$payment->getId();
```

The online code sample (http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/doc/payments/CreatePaymentUsingPayPal.html) shows how to send the request, however it does not include the getId() method.

To find this out I had to look in the downloaded SDK files at the file sample\payments\CreatePayment.php which has the following example code showing the use of this method:

```
ResultPrinter::printResult('Create Payment Using Credit Card', 'Payment', $payment->getId(), $request, $payment);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this link to be extremely helpful, in case anyone wants to check it out: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/issues/79

Comment: This post isn't an actual attempt at answering the question. Please note [StackOverflow doesn't work like a discussion forum](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), it is a Q&A site where every post is either a question or an answer to a question. Posts can also have [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) - small sentences like this one - that can be used to critique or request clarification from an author. This should be either a comment or a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Answer (score 0):

Since the v1/payments API has been deprecated for some time now, the best solution is to use the current v2/checkout/orders API for all new integrations. The order ID is returned in the URL.

However, redirects are an old integration method, for old websites. It is preferred to not use any redirects, at all, and keep your site loaded at ALL times. Instead use this approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Answer (score -1):

1. `paymentid`:

After you created the payment, in return json, you can get paymentid.
like this: "id":"PAY-01K00482KX842131HKORKVKY"

1. `payerid`:

you can use API:GET /v1/payments/payment/{paymentId}  to get payer id after user approved the payment,and you will find payerid in return json,like this:

```
{
    "id":"PAY-01K00482KX842131HKORKVKY",
    "create_time":"2014-06-19T09:17:31Z",
    "update_time":"2014-06-19T09:17:31Z",
    "state":"created",
    "intent":"sale",
    "payer":{
            "payment_method":"paypal",
            "payer_info":{
                    "email":"buyer@samsung.com",
                    "first_name":"buyer",
                    "last_name":"samsung",
                    "payer_id":"H2DKRTTYWW8HS",
                    "shipping_address":{                                              "line1":"Lushan Road Num.188",                                              "line2":"JianYe",
                                              "city":"Tucson",
                                                   "state":"AZ",   
                                                   "postal_code":"85715", 
                                                   "country_code":"US",
                                                    "recipientName":"buyer samsung"}}},
    "transactions":[{
                           "amount":{
                                        "total":"12.00",
                                        "currency":"USD",
                                        "details"{"subtotal":"12.00"}},
                 "description":"creating a payment"}],
    "links":[
                   {"href":"xxxxxxx","rel":"self","method":"GET"},
              {"href":"xxxxxxx","rel":"approval_url","method":"REDIRECT"},
              {"href":"xxxxxxx","rel":"execute","method":"POST"}]}
```

Comment: I need the same number in checkout.php (executed before payment) as in pay.php (executed after payment).. what you show here is only the after part...